# Generate random records from the table tblFruit based on the field Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, generate

I will need your help to generate random records from the table tblFruit based on the field Type (without no duplication)

[image: Table: tblFruit]

As per the above table.

There are 4 type of fruit number 1,2,3,4

I want to generate x records dynamically from the table tblFruit (e.g 7 records). 
Let say I need to get 7 random record of fruit .

My result should contains fruit of the different types. However, we need to ensure that the result contains only 7 records.

i.e 
2 records of type 1,
2 records of type 2,
2 records of type 3,
1 records of type 4

e.g

[image: My Result]

Note: If i want to generate 10 records (without no duplication), 
then i will get 2 records of each type and the two remaining records randomly of any type.

Much grateful for your help.

Comment: Sql Server. Thx

Comment: What version of SQL SERVER?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 with IIS Express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might suggest:

```
select top (7) f.*
from tblfruit f
order by row_number() over (partition by type order by newid());
```

This will actually produce a result with approximately the same number of rows of each type (well, off by 1), but that meets your needs.

Comment: @Tairon . . . That could only occur if there are more types than rows you are trying to return.